# Does the GitHub Windows client replace the git command line?

Tags: git, github

Does the official GitHub Windows client replace the git command line in whole or in part? The main page here does not say:

http://windows.github.com/

And I can't find this info elsewhere. I could simply download the Windows client and try it out but I'd rather get my question answered before needlessly installing another app.

Specifically, can I use the Windows client to do `git commit`, `git push`, `git pull`?

Will the Windows client provide the capability of other commands? If so, which ones?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "replace".

Comment: Added some specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can use the Windows client to do all of those easily. SourceTree works well too. The Github application uses some slightly different terminology from the command line interface, but you can see it here https://help.github.com/articles/synchronizing-repositories .

Comment: Updated. The GitHub desktop client does not support everything on the git command line. It's probably not even close, in my opinion. Scott Chacon, who works at GitHub, in his book _Pro Git_ says this: "...only at the command line is the full power of Git completely at your disposal." https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Graphical-Interfaces

Comment: It would be nice if GitHub documented exactly what the GitHub capabilities are versus the command line.